# Resolvconf using gateway instead of specified nameserver for DNS

Tags: linux, networking, dns, raspberry-pi

Screenshot from terminal:

[image: Screenshot from terminal]

In short, I have my interface set to static, and have the dns-nameserver specified, so DHCP shouldn't be impacting this.

I have specified the nameserver in `/etc/resolvconf/resolv.conf.d/base`

The `resolv.conf` file specifies that it was generated by resolvconf, so I don't think it's an issue of conflicting DNS programs (although for sanity checking, I verified systemd-resolved is disabled).

I am not sure what I am missing here, or even how to proceed with troubleshooting.

Currently using Raspbian 11, and resolvconf 3.12.0.

Answer (score 0):

Simple typo in your config: You've currently used `dns-nameserver`, which is lacking a trailing `s`. The correct option would be `dns-nameservers`.

`resolvconf` is usually automatically managed and you should not edit your DNS manually there, as `/etc/resolv.conf` gets overwritten by your network manager.

If you use `NetworkManager` or `systemd-networkd`, you need to setup your network details in its specific configuration of course.

Comment: I have corrected the typo, rebooted, and it does not appear to be the sole issue. I am aware about not editing the `resolv.conf` manually, the issue is that the auto-generated version by `resolvconf` is not what I would expect. I do not use NetworkManager or systemd-networkd, and nothing appears to be overwriting the `resolv.conf` besides `resolvconf` itself.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that even though I am not using dhcp, apparently at one point in the early server config I was.

File `/run/resolvconf/interfaces/eth0.dhcp` had a nameserver specified in there; for some reason `resolvconf` was using this and none of the other specified `resolvconf` specific configs, even though I am not using the `eth0` interface at the moment.

Editing this file appears to resolve my problem.